# Pause until variable has changed

Tags: android, date, calendar

I have a question: How do I pause an activity until a certain variable is changed?

I've wrote 2 classes, one for a LocationListener and one that creates an instance of this LocationListener class:

The first class:

```
LocationGetter locgetter = new LocationGetter();
LocationManager locmanag = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locmanag.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locgetter);
mLat = locgetter.getLat();
mLong = locgetter.getLon();
```

The LocationListener class:

```
public class LocationGetter implements LocationListener {

double mLat = 0.0;
double mLong = 0.0;

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
if(location != null){
    mLat = location.getLatitude();
    mLong = location.getLongitude();
}
```

Now, I want the code in the first class to pause until the getLatitude and getLongitude getters are actually returning a value other than 0. There is a reason I don't want to continue before getting longitude and latitude, I will show a progressbar if this works. I know the onLocationChanged method will only run if there is an location, but the first class will continue executing anyway.

I'm really new to Android, so excuse me if I've overlooked something quite obvious.

Comment: I don't think "pause" is a right word to use in this case...and yeah you can use a ProgressBar, whats wrong with that??

Answer (score 2):

Well you could do

```
while (value == 0.0) {
    // do nothing
}
// now use value
```

but that's a really bad idea. You would get "Application Not Responding". Also 
*you must not pause your Activity,* never ever - and it is not necessary.

What you should do is to add a way to notify your code that wants to use the values once they change.
The easiest way with LocationListeners is implementing them directly in your Activity. like so:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    onCreate() {
        locmanag.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // now change the ui. This is called on UI thread.
    }
}
```

If you want the location to be handled by a different class you can still notify your activity about changes.

If you want to use your LocationListener from just one Activity that would work:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private LocationGetter mGetter;

    onCreate() {
        mGetter = new LocationGetter(this);
        locmanag.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mGetter);
    }

    public void somethingHappend() {
        mGetter.getLat();
    }
}

public class LocationGetter implements LocationListener {

    private final MyActivity mActivity;
    public LocationGetter(MyActivity activity) {
        mActivity= activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(location != null){
        mLat = location.getLatitude();
        mLong = location.getLongitude();
        if (mActivity!= null) {
            mActivity.somethingHappend();
        }
    }

    public long getLat() {
        return mLat;
    }
}
```

If you want to use your LocationListener from different Activities you should implement a common Interface (like LocationListener is)

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements LocationGetter.MyCallback {
    private LocationGetter mGetter;

    onCreate() {
        mGetter = new LocationGetter(this);
        locmanag.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mGetter);
    }

    public void somethingHappend() {
        mGetter.getLat();
    }
}

public class LocationGetter implements LocationListener {
    public Interface MyCallback {
        // you could pass lat + long here
        public void somethingHappend();
    }

    private final MyCallback mCallback;
    public LocationGetter(MyCallback callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(location != null){
        mLat = location.getLatitude();
        mLong = location.getLongitude();
        if (mCallback != null) {
            mCallback.somethingHappend();
        }
    }

    public long getLat() {
        return mLat;
    }
}
```

Instead of creating a new callback interface you could also use LocationListener from all your Activities. Works as well but does not show you how those callbacks work :)

Another possbility is to use e.g. Handler (especially if the other thing is executed in a different Thread)

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements Handler.Callback {
    private Handler mHandler;

    onCreate() {
        mHandler = new Handler(this);
        mGetter = new LocationGetter(mHandler);
        locmanag.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mGetter);
    }

    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // msg.what would be 0, that's what we send
        mGetter.getLat();
        // we are in UI thread here. safe to modify.
        return true;
    }
}

public class LocationGetter implements LocationListener {

    private final Handler mHandler;
    public LocationGetter(Handler handler) {
        mHandler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(location != null){
        mLat = location.getLatitude();
        mLong = location.getLongitude();
        if (mHandler != null) {
            // you can send a lot more here
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }

    public long getLat() {
        return mLat;
    }
}
```

Besides waiting for LocationListener isn't even possible if you try that from your Activity UI thread since you get the update on the UI Thread which is blocked by your waiting. So you never get the update.

Answer (score 1):

Wait is a good option, if you're multi threading, as it works nicely with notify() and notifyAll();

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using some form of synchronisation, like a `java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier`. Call `CyclicBarrier#await()` in Thread-1 and then it will wait until you also call it in Thread-2